# How to add prefix slug in static wordpress page?

Tags: pages

I have a static wordpress page - http://example.com/trade. I need, that this page open on http://example.com/tender/trade. So, how can I add 'trade' prefix in this case?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to create a page with slug `tender` and create another page with slug `trade` and set `tender` as the parent page. Have a look at this [article](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#To_create_a_subpage).

And the complicated way is to add a new rewrite rule.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule - this is it?

Comment: Yes, but if you're not going to use `tender` extensively then it's better to stick with the parent-child relation.